# Is it possible to use a script or a program to force-read a protected file off the disk?

Tags: c++, recovery

Some files are only able to be read by root users. However, I am curious to know if the theory of data recovery can be applied here to force read the file off of the disk. Is it possible to scan the bytes of the file, especially since we know that the file exists? (In contrast to recovery where the bits might be overwritten.)

The process I can think of is as follows:

```
//Get the starting block location of the file

//Read it

// get the next block location

// read it

// iterate until done...
```

I have two questions here. Is this possible if the file in question is only readable by users with permissions higher than your own? Even if so, how would I implement this in code?

Comment: I don't think you can get the starting block location of the file on the disk without permission (The OS won't tell you where it is, even if you bypass all the read/write functions), and the file probably is not contiguous, so I think this task is impossible.

Comment: ... plus you will need to have permission to access the raw data in the disk in the first place, which in most cases you do not have (i.e. is restricted to the admin/root user) The security of the data in the OS depends on you not being able to do this, a system that allowed you to bypass the permissions that easy might be just as good without protection in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want *also* requires administrative access. If you try to read or write the raw block device files `/dev/sd*` or `/dev/hd*` on Linux systems, or their equivalents on other Unix systems, or using raw Windows API calls to read block devices, you'll invariably find that they require administrative privileges. (`CAP_SYS_RAWIO` on Linux.)

Furthermore, if the block device is currently mounted, the data you read that describes the filesystem layout might be changing out from underneath you -- making this approach remarkably unreliable for mounted drives.

If you wish to pursue this further, I strongly recommend looking at the `debugfs(8)` ext2, ext3, ext4 debugging tool. It implements the ext* family of filesystems entirely in userspace and allows working with block devices at a raw level.

Answer (score 0):

If you can obtain the hard drive, mount it as a secondary hard drive. This way, user file level permissions would not be an issue as you would be root/Administrator and could chmod the files however you like. You might also create a forensics images of the drive using dd (or some other tool) to do a bit for bit copy and then mount that image and read/copy/examine the files.

There's no way to do this on a live operating system. If you could read root's files when he did not want you to, you would have found a major security exploit in the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible if, for example, the Unix sysadmin has foolishly left the block or raw devices readable by non-trusted users.  But the point of an operating system is to mediate between users/applications and system resources like disks, so you won't find many systems set up to allow this sort of access by default.  In the case of Unix systems, key pieces of information aren't available to your if the disk devices in /dev are not readable.  You can't know the starting block location of a file, for example.